# Method to query DB on a column set as string which stores Timestamp information

Tags: mysql, database, hibernate, casting, hql

I have a DB field which was set as String and its storing timestamp information.(Which was mistake in first place). Now I face the challenge of querying the table using that column as if it was TimeStamp information(Basically using between operator).

I am using Hibernate and I tried using the CAST operator as

```
select * 
from table 
where cast(columName as Timestamp) between startTime and endTime
```

And unfortunately this doesn't work. Is there a way in which I can accomplish this query using hibernate?

Comment: If the string fields are always of the same format, it will be easier to add a timestamp column and transfer the values from string to DateTime.  It will make everything else much simpler.

Comment: Thats correct. But we can't change it because initially it was storing some other information, which we have to still persist.

Comment: Put the other information in it's own column.  If you have other information with a different format (or not a date at all), your "between" query will fail anyway.

Comment: "Doesn't work" means what? Errors? No results? Sits on couch all day?